# android simple JSON payload to websocket

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I am trying to send a simple JSON payload via a websocket in android.
I did it in python like this:

```
self.connection = websocket.create_connection(url, config["timeout"])
self.connection.send(payload)
```

and that's it.

but in JAVA it's all way too complicated and I saw in some places that I need to use okhttp3 sockets, other places I saw that I need to convert it into bytes.. and I'm not sure on how to aproach it with JAVA for android.